# How can i fix this warning: CoreSimulator is attempting to unload a stale CoreSimulatorService job

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, xcode8, xcodebuild

I have a warning in my build log in teamcity. I've updated Xcode on my CI-Server from 7.3.1 to 8. The step run successfully but I have this:

```
[Step 3/3] Starting: /Users/teamcity/local/teamcity-build-agent/temp/agentTmp/custom_scriptxxxxxxx
[Step 3/3] in directory: /Users/teamcity/local/teamcity-build-agent/work/yyyy
[Step 3/3] 2016-10-11 09:04:41.706 xcodebuild[18180:5010256] CoreSimulator is attempting to unload a stale CoreSimulatorService job.  Detected Xcode.app relocation or CoreSimulatorService version change.  Framework path (/Applications/Xcodes/Xcode_8.0.app/Contents/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSimulator.framework) and version (303.8) does not match existing job path (/Applications/Xcodes/Xcode-7.3.1.app/Contents/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSimulator.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService.xpc) and version (209.19).
[Step 3/3] 2016-10-11 09:04:41.961 xcodebuild[18180:5010256] Failed to locate a valid instance of CoreSimulatorService in the bootstrap.  Adding it now.
```

How can i fix this warning?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

I had the same issue. I've to run both Xcode 7 (to build old version) and Xcode 8 (to build current develop branch) in my Jenkins server and I was having the issue all the time.

Solution:

```
launchctl remove com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService || true
```

This happens because, even if you quit the simulator app, the service is still running. The above command is needed to remove the service called `com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService`. The `|| true` is to avoid failure when that service is not running.

Comment: Love to find quick solutions like this - Thanks

Comment: Could You please explain why it happened? What's the root cause?

Comment: quick solution is good. but could you explain what this bash script do, please?

Comment: I just added a short explanation

Comment: Fixed this error for me: ERROR | [watchOS] unknown: Encountered an unknown error (434: unexpected token at ) during validation.

Answer (score 0):

Encountered the same issue and solved with the following steps:

1. Copy Xcode from the Applications folder to another location
2. Delete the copy left in Applications & make sure no copies of Xcode remain
3. Move the copy from step 1 back to the Applications folder
4. Restarted machine

It appears that some value is not being set, since Xcode is not being installed through the App store.