# Pod Spec Lint CoreSimulator detected Xcode.app relocation or CoreSimulatorService version change

Tags: ios, cocoapods

The command `pod spec lint` fails. I couldn't find a similar question here on SO and on Cocoapod's repo. Full log:

> -> GPKit (0.1.1)
>       - ERROR | [iOS] unknown: Encountered an unknown error (757: unexpected token at '2017-08-17 16:12:08.932 simctl[55281:678990]
>   CoreSimulator detected Xcode.app relocation or CoreSimulatorService
>   version change.  Framework path
>   (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSimulator.framework)
>   and version (375.21) does not match existing job path
>   (/Library/Developer/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSimulator.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService.xpc)
>   and version (459.13).  Attempting to remove the stale service in order
>   to add the expected version. ') during validation.
>
> Analyzed 1 podspec.
>
> [!] The spec did not pass validation, due to 1 error.

Any solution for this? And why it happens?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

For reference, I've managed to solve this problem. I found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40258881/3231194

Though the question is about CI.

In short, the solution I got was from Luca, run this:

`launchctl remove com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService || true`

As for the explanation what caused the problem, I think it's because I have and run two versions of Xcode. 8.3 and 9.0.

Answer (score 3):

I run into this issue and solved it by changing the `Command Line Tools` in Xcode (Xcode > Preferences > Locations) as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41536029/4196117

Bottom line, I was using a different Xcode version for the command line tools than the one I was actively using for my project.

**Update**: image for reference
[image]

Comment: Thank you! I'm running multiple versions of XCode to support different applications and this fixes my fastlane lane.  In my lane, I call git_commit, push_to_git_remote, add_git_tag, push_to_git_remote, and pod_push.  The solution here with 'launchctl remove' didn't help fix my issue.

Comment: @NickN I think you are referring to the other response, have you tried this workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41536029/4196117?