# 'pod spec lint' fails after project conversion to Swift 4

Tags: swift, cocoapods, swift4, uifontdescriptor

After converting my cocoa framework project to Swift 4 the class ***UIFontDescriptorFamilyAttribute*** is now ***UIFontDescriptor.AttributeName.family***, so I changed my code from:

```
// Swift 3    
UIFontDescriptor(fontAttributes: [UIFontDescriptorFamilyAttribute: fontFamiliy])
```

to

```
// Swift 4
UIFontDescriptor(fontAttributes: [UIFontDescriptor.AttributeName.family: fontFamiliy])
```

However, when I try -***pod spec lint***- I get next error:

```
- ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild:  SerializableLabel.swift:108:68: error: type 'UIFontDescriptor' has no member 'AttributeName'
```

Is cocoapods somehow not aware yet of Swift 4? Do I have to update something else in my configuration?

My config:

**.podspec**

```
s.pod_target_xcconfig = { 'SWIFT_VERSION' => '4.0' }
```

**cocoapods**

```
$ pod --version
1.3.1
```

Comment: MAYBE this could help you, just maybe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45730217/pod-spec-lint-coresimulator-detected-xcode-app-relocation-or-coresimulatorservic/45732214#45732214

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't, still having the same issue.

Comment: Are you still having this problem?

Comment: Yes, I am. The problem is still there. https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/7057

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to make a file named .swift-version and inside just put 4.0

**Update for Cocoapods >= 1.5**

you now use `s.swift_version = '4.1'` in your podspec

Answer (score 1):

To lint for different versions of Swift:

#### With CocoaPods 1.3.1 or newer

```bash
# example for Swift 4.0
echo "4.0" > .swift-version
pod lib lint
```

#### With CocoaPods 1.4.0 or newer

```bash
# example for Swift 4.0
pod lib lint --swift-version=4.0
```

Comment: I Love you too! haha
Thanks!